# Create folder in sd card

Tags: android, directory, sd-card, ddms, android-file

Alright so I created 2 folders in the SD card using the following code:

```
String folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AllAroundMe/Images/";
      File file = new File(folderPath);
      if(!file.exists())
      {
            if(file.mkdirs());
                      Log.d("MyTag","Successfully created folders");
      }
```

I tested this program and it really works, the logcat prints the success message above.

But if I navigate to my sd card I don't see "AllAroundMe" folder.

How can I access that folder from my computer?

Comment: go through this -- http://facebooksso.blogspot.in/

Comment: i Tried your code after add permission and see what happned. I add image also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this 
Open DDMS perspective -> File Explorer - > mnt -> sdcard

Comment: Great it works, why I'm not able to see it from the window explorer? Anyways, I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Android DDMS FIleExplorer-->mnt-->sdcard--> and search for your sdcard folder which is created by you

Answer (score 0):

- First i hope you have given the `External Storage` **permission** in your `Manifest.xml`
- Do something like this... i know what you did right, but still i prefer this approach.

  File f = new File("/sdcard/AllAroundMe/Images/");
- Now browse your sdcard from you pc, i am sure you will find the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just check u can`t give the permission in manifest file in your Application just add the permission of this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Than run your own code the folder has been create in sdcard ok check this.